# Dynamically inserting a property with event properties

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to create a general handler for an arrays of inputs. In my state, I have properties that are arrays, like the following:

```
const [state, useState] = useState({
  arr1: [''],
  arr2: [''],
  arr3: ['']
});
const handleArrayChange = (index, e) => {
  const val = [...state.[e.target.name]];
  val[index] = e.target.value;
  setState({...state, [e.target.name]: [...val]})
};
```

Then, my input fields use Material UI TextFields, and the user can dynamically add more fields:

```
const array1List = [...state.arr1].map((item, index) => (
  <TextField name='arr1' onChange={(e) => handleArrayInputs(index, e)} variant='outlined' ... />
  //Some button that will add more fields
));
const array2List = [...state.arr2].map((item, index) => (
  <TextField name='arr2' onChange={(e) => handleArrayInputs(index, e)} variant='outlined' ... />
  //Some button that will add more fields
));
....
```

This works in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mcclintock-pgowm?file=/src/App.js). However, I get a `Parsing error` eslint in my editor on the `[...data.[e.target.name]]`. I don't get the problem why it works in codesandbox but not in my editor.

Comment: there's a typo, it should be `[...data[e.target.name]]`,

Comment: @AKX I edited the handler to match the name. Yes there is still the same parsing error, but that is why im confused. Despite the error, it still works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't get the problem why it works in codesandbox but not in my editor.

Well, it's not like your editor does anything to really make code work, it just edits text.

The ESlint parser chokes on `data.[e.target.name]`, which is in my opinion invalid JavaScript syntax (`data[e.target.name]` is correct), but for some reason the Babel transpiler underlying Codesandbox [accepts that just fine](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYwLwwNoDofQVAUywyKgQCcBzAqLMBAWwIF1mBuIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.15&externalPlugins=).

Chances are it would work just fine with whatever transpilation tool you're using locally (maybe Create React App, so it'd be Babel running in Webpack), but ESlint doesn't like it.